# click event not working from dynamically generated HTML angular 2

Tags: angular

I am creating tables rows when the `http.get` method updates me ... on receiving data I create table rows using JS / jquery in the angular 2 version.

My Code:

```html
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>BAJAJ-AUTO</td>
    <td>14.284%</td>
    <td>27/12/2013 12:00 am</td>
    <td>30/12/2013 12:00 am</td>
    <td>1935</td>
    <td>30/12/2013 12:00 am</td>
    <td>1935</td>
    <td>31/12/2013 12:00 am</td>
    <td>2120</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="processAdvise('BAJAJ-AUTO')">Process Advise</button></td>
</tr>
```

so the last the `td` - has a button which shall call my angular 2 function to process it - This code doesnt reaches even at the start of the function

I also tried this to no avail:

- `(click)` for angular 2
- `onclick` and kept the function in the same HTML template using
  script tag

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you try to accomplish?

Comment: i want the click event to fires up a angular 2 function ... but the click event code in html is created dynamically ... (which is based on http service of angular 2)

Comment: i want to .. fill the table row data into another form which is present on that page - so basically the JS function will read the row and then fill up the required html form

Answer (score 6):

Angular2 doesn't process HTML outside of a components template in any way, therefore it is expected `(click)="processAdvise('BAJAJ-AUTO')` doesn't work.

`onclick="processAdvise('BAJAJ-AUTO')"` also won't work when `processAdvise()` is a method of an Angular2 component because `onclick` is HTML-only and functions assigned this way are searched in the global JS scope not inside a components class.

`<script>` tags are remove from Angular2 templates

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  ....
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {
  }

  addHtml() {
    // add the HTML to the DOM
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => this.handleClick(event));
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    // doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: so what is the possible solution to overcome this problem ?

Comment: See my comment below your question.

Comment: let me tryout this and update after it - Thanx in advance :)

Comment: I tried this solution not working for me.Did any one find the solution means please provide.

Comment: "Didn't not work" doesn't provide information anyone can act on. I'd suggest you create a new question with the code that demonstrates what you tried, and what the expected and actual behavior is (and the error message if there is one)

Comment: this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('button') does not select dynamically added elements. How can dynamically added elements be selected?

Comment: @mad_fox Why do you think that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution I tried and it worked.
Assign your component object to Window object in the constructor like the following:

```
...
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private emService: SomeService) {
Window["myComponent"] = this;}

onClickAJS(){alert('it works!')}
...
```

Then you can access members of the component from DOM onclick="Window.myComponent.onClickAJS()". Also, you can call it from the browser console like : Window.myComponent.onClickAJS(), should work as well. It is a hackish way. 
More appropriate way is to create a component for your generated HTML and load it at run time. Here is the article to get you started.
[dynamic components](https://fromjami.com/2017/06/26/load-components-dynamically-at-runtime-in-angular-4/)

Comment: whast is myComponent

Comment: myComponent is the key string to store/retrieve the saved value ('this' is the value in that case).