# How to put a click functionality in jqwidgets (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jqgrid

I used jq widgets in angular 2 but I failed in calling a function when the button is clicked.

Here is my code,

```
   var cellsrenderer = function (row, column, value ) {
        return '<button (click)="open(value)">edit</button>';

    }

    this.columns =
        [
            {
                text: 'S.NO', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input',  width: 100, cellsalign: 'center'
            },
            {
                text: 'Name', columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'input', datafield: 'name', width: 215
            },
            {
                text: 'Actions', filtertype: 'input',datafield: 'id', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer, width: 80, filterable: false
            }
        ];
}
```

Here when I debug the functioon it self is not calling so that I cant redirect to the next page according to my requirement.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: This won't work in ng2, it doesn't handle html that way. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053067/click-event-not-working-from-dynamically-generated-html-angular-2

Comment: Did you get any solution of this question?